# GeoListPlot and ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, geographics

I'm doing a research and I have to add to a `GeoListPlot` a `ListContourPlot`, but it doesn't work with simple `Show` and I have no idea how to make it working

[image: GeoListPlot image]
[image: ListContourPlot plot]

As you can see these points doesn't match well... but they're plotted from the same data. Does anyone know how to make it working?

Comment: What code was used to produce these? Very hard to reverse engineer this from images.

Answer (score 4):

[`GeoListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoListPlot) uses [`GeoProjection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoProjection)/[`GeoModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoModel) when constructing the output. This means the data points do not match the latitude-longitude coordinates as shown in a equirectangular projection, which is effectively what [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot) uses. One possibility to fix this is to extract the projection coordinates from [`GeoListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoListPlot). Here is some sample data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
coords = Thread[{RandomReal[{35,45}, 10], RandomReal[{-90,-80}, 10]}];
coordValues = RandomInteger[10, 10];
```

Here is a method to get a list of rules to convert the latitude-longitude coordinates `coords` into the projection coordinates used by [`GeoListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoListPlot):

```
g = GeoListPlot[Tooltip[GeoPosition[#], #]& /@ coords]
rules = Cases[g, Tooltip[Inset[_, geo_], latlong_List] :> latlong->geo, Infinity]
```

[image]

> {{35.6574, -81.7484} -> {-81.7484, 
>      38.2106}, {36.1142, -82.5134} -> {-82.5134, 
>      38.7744}, {36.878, -87.5251} -> {-87.5251, 
>      39.7246}, {37.3115, -84.2194} -> {-84.2194, 
>      40.2681}, {37.4136, -80.2283} -> {-80.2283, 
>      40.3965}, {38.9601, -87.0713} -> {-87.0713, 
>      42.3641}, {40.4225, -80.7472} -> {-80.7472, 
>      44.2647}, {42.0047, -87.9195} -> {-87.9195, 
>      46.3682}, {42.8953, -85.7715} -> {-85.7715, 
>      47.5752}, {43.1739, -87.8817} -> {-87.8817, 47.9564}}

Now, we construct a dataset using the `geo` coordinates and the `coordValues` above:

```
dataset = Join[coords /. rules, List/@coordValues, 2];
```

Here is a [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot) of dataset:

```
plot = ListContourPlot[dataset, Mesh->All]
```

[image]

Finally, we can add the [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot) output to the [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics) object produced by [`GeoListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoListPlot):

```
Show[g, Epilog -> First @ plot]
```

[image]

Notice how the `ListContourPlot` output matches up with the coordinates in the `GeoListPlot` output.

Comment: Using the option `ContourShading -> None` in definition of `plot` enables the map to show.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in how `GeoListPlot` and `ContourListPlot` interpret their coordinates. `GeoListPlot` displays latitude on the vertical axis and longitude on the horizontal axis. `ContourListPlot` displays X values on the horizontal axis and Y values on the vertical axis. The order of the horizontal and vertical coordinates are reversed.

Here's a list of points, where each point is latitude, longitude, and elevation in meters.

```
points = {
  {37.80241, -122.4432, 7.},
  {37.77555, -122.4279, 46.},
  {37.80316, -122.4271, 26.},
  {37.80600, -122.4375, 5.},
  {37.78155, -122.4362, 44.},
  {37.78379, -122.4573, 63.},
  {37.77206, -122.4403, 76.},
  {37.76710, -122.4212, 9.},
  {37.76705, -122.4160, 4.},
  {37.79626, -122.4434, 47.}
};
```

We can plot the points on a map with:

```
map = GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[points]]
```

[image: GeoListPlot]

Here's a contour plot of these points. This demonstrates the problem. Notice that negative longitude values are plotted on the vertical axis, and the latitude values are on the horizontal axis.

```
ListContourPlot[points, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: ListContourPlot with reversed axes]

Solve the problem by simply reversing the X and Y points for `ListContourPlot`.

```
xypoints = #[[{2, 1, 3}]] & /@ points;
contours = ListContourPlot[xypoints, Mesh -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: ListContourPlot with corrected axes]

The points on the map and contours now correspond.

```
Show[map, ListContourPlot[xypoints, Mesh -> All, ContourShading -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[points], GeoProjection->"Albers"]` to see why you can't simply use `ListContourPlot` with reversed coordinates in general.

Comment: @Carl Yes, the swapping-coordinates method only works for the Mercator projection, but it has an advantage in that the `ListContourPlot` axes show the correct latitude and longitude without the need to find corrected values for `DataRange`. For example, the southernmost tip of Lake Michigan is at 42 N, and not nearly 46 N as the transformation plots imply. Did the question ask for a generalized coordinate transform, or rather, simply a way to match a `GeoListPlot` to a `ListContourPlot`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `GeoPosition` and `GeoGridPosition` to get the projection of `coords`.

Using @Carl's example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
coords = Thread[{RandomReal[{35,45}, 10], RandomReal[{-90,-80}, 10]}];
coordValues = RandomInteger[10, 10];
```

Create projected coordinates for `coords` and combine with `coordValues`:

```
procejtedcoords = (GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition@#, "Equirectangular"]&/@coords)[[All,1]];

lcpdata = Join[procejtedcoords, List /@ coordValues, 2];
Show[g, ListContourPlot[lcpdata, Mesh -> All, BaseStyle->Opacity[.5]]]
```

[image]